# how to install ourmon detection tool

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

new bee in fedora and try to install ourmon detection tool and got stuck in this below error please help me to figure out

when i run configure.pl the error message shows

```
cc: error: /usr/lib/libJudy.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [ourmon] Error 1
ourmon compile failed
you need pre-installed: 1. libJudy.a, 2. libpcre.a, and 3. libpcap.a
See INSTALL file for more info.
you may need to get a new libpcap library from tcpdump.org
or try making src/ourmon/ourmon by hand.
config terminated.
[root@localhost mrourmon]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have `libpcap-devel` installed - you should be able to install it with:

`sudo yum install libpcap-devel`

Comment: Thanks Tomh installed it properly and also run test.c program for testing ... it generate the desire output also so what was the other problem ?

Answer (score 0):

install libpcap.a and libJudy.a file in usr/lib